# How to add Devexpress to C# project

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm learning programming myself. I have a C# source code but I can't run it.

[image]

By google, I tried install DevExpress but it's not ok. Pls help me add DevExpress and many thanks with love

Comment: I'd suggest you publish your educational project on Github so people could see what you're doing wrong. There could be many reasons for this behavior and screenshot is not enough to figure out what is a cause.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have the correct version of DevExpress installed. If this is a sample using an older version you can try to use the Project Converter, this is found under the menu item DevExpress -> Project Converter. You can also remove the currently referenced dlls and add them manually from the install directory (\components\bin\framework).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried istall DevExpress 16.1 but it's not ok.

Comment: you need to install 15.2 or upgrade the project to 16.1